# Thread Safe Server Querier

Tags: java, multithreading, android, thread-safety

I wanted to make a class that connects to my server and returns a value, a URL in this case. As Android 4.0 doesn't let me run network task on the main UI thread (rightly so) I have made this.

Please give me your feedback as to if it is thread safe or not and ways to improve it. I have never used `ExecutorService` or `Future` before so I would be grateful to know if I am using it correctly. I would also like to know if this is blocking the thread that called `getDownloadURL`.

```
public class DownloadURLServerGetter implements DownloadURLGetter {

    private ServerAdapter serverAdapter;
    private String id;

    @Inject
    public DownloadURLServerGetter(ServerAdapter serverAdapter) {
        this.serverAdapter = serverAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized String getDownloadURL(String id) throws IOException {
        this.id = id;
        final ExecutorService service;
        final Future<String> task;

        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        task = service.submit(new MyCallable());
        try {
            return task.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }


    public class MyCallable implements Callable<String> {

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {

            HttpResponse resp = serverAdapter.get("blobs/" + id);
            String url = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
            return Parser.parseURL(url);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method seems thread safe, but you are blocking `getDownloadURL()` because `task.get()` will only return once the underlying job finishes. Try reading up on Java's  `future` and see how you can use them more efficient and correct.

Your executor service should most likely only be created once for your application.

By the way: if you pass `ServerAdapter` and `id` to `MyCallable` (as constructor arguments) you no longer need to keep `getDownloadURL` synchronized or `MyCallable` non-static.

Comment: thank you for that. I realised I was blocking the calling thread. I have actually modified the thread that was calling this method so it seems to work pretty well at the moment tho as you pointed out there is room for improvement.